# A Question about the Intuition Behind the Definition of an Interior Point on Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On page 32 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, in section 2.18 (e), the following definition is introduced:

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $p \in X$ and $E \subseteq X$. p is called an *interior point* of $E$ if there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N \subseteq E$.

As I understand it, the idea of an interior point intuitively is that if $E$ is a subset of a metric space, then a point which is "inside" $E$, or in other words, "not on the edge" of $E$, we would call an interior point.

If that's really the idea behind the mathematical term - an interior point, then I think that the following example is an interior point according to the definition, but not really an interior point according to the idea:
the set $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is a metric space, since $\mathbb{R}^1$, just like any Euclidean space is a metric space and any subset of a metric space is also a metric space. If you put $E = X$, and $p = 3$, then $p$ is an interior point of $E$, since you can take $E = N_3(p)$ as a neighborhood of $p$ and obviously $E \subseteq E$. But intuitevly, you would say that $p$ is on the edge of $E$ and not inside of $E$.

So does the example I've given is not actually an interior point, or am I'm missing the idea behind the term interior point?

Answer (score 2):

The concept being defined has three objects given: the metric space $X$; the point $p \in X$; and the subset $E \subset X$.

The author uses the terminology "$x$ is an interior point of $E$", without referring to $X$, because $X$ is considered the "background" topological space and does not need special mention.

Nonetheless, it might be somewhat clearer to incorporate $X$ into the terminology, and some authors do just this. So, copying that somewhat lengthier but clearer terminology, we say that *$x$ is an interior point of $E$* **relative to $X$**  if there exists a subset $N \subset X$ such that $N$ is a neighborhood of $p$ and $N \subset E$.

In your example, it is true that if $X = E = \{1,2,3\}$ and if $p = 3$ then $p$ is an interior point of $E$ relative to $X$, using the neighborhood $N = \{3\}$. The point is that $X$ is a discrete metric space and therefore *every subset is open*, including the subset $N = \{3\}$. That's just how things go in a discrete metric space. It's a lonely place, you are the only one in your neighborhood.

However, if $X = \mathbb R$ and $E = \{1,2,3\}$ and $p=3$ then $x$ is not an interior point of $E$ relative to $X$.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong but we can also take $N = \{1,2,3\}$ as a neighbourhood of $3$ to demonstrate that $3$ is an interior point of  $\{1,2,3\}$  relative to $\{1,2,3\}$, right? Also, if you take $X = [1, 3]$ and $E = [2, 3]$ and $p = 3$, would'nt the neighbuorhood $N = [2.5, 3]$  (i.e. $N_{\frac{1}{2}}(3)$) for instance, make $p$ an interior point of $E$ relative to $X$? And doesn't it goes against the idea of interior points, I described in the question? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: One trouble with formal mathematical definitions is that although they may be crafted to reflect some notion of our intuition, nonetheless in the process of formalization and abstraciton, our intuition has to adapt. That is the case with the concept of interior. So yes, perhaps this violates your intuition of interior, but it nonetheless remains true that any subset $N \subset X=\{1,2,3\}$ *whatsoever* that contains $3$ functions as a witness to verifying that $3$ is an interior point of $E = \{1,2,3\}$ relative to $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So essentially the intuition, I described in the question was wrong, right? Is my second example valid? If my problem is a misunderstanding of the intuition behind the definition of an interior point, then could you explain what is the idea behind the formal definition of an interior point?

Comment: I'm not saying that your intuition is wrong. Certainly it is fruitful to use our intuitions in order to understand concepts of topology, metric spaces, open sets, neighborhoods, etc. But one must be careful not to let one's intuition run wild, not to *over-interpret* the meaning of a mathematical concept based on a word chosen as an aid our intuition.

Answer (score 0):

The subset $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$ with the Euclidean Metric has no interior points. As any neighborhood around 1, 2, or 3 would contain points outside of $X$. Where your analysis breaks down is that the requirement is that $E \subseteq X$ in order for the point to be an interior point, not $E \subseteq E$

Comment: It's obvious that $E \subseteq X$, since $E = X$. When I wrote $E \subseteq E$, I meant that the neighbourhood of $p$ which is also equal to $E$, is a subset of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is an interior point of a subset $E$, then there is some neighbourhood $N \subset E$ which contains $p$. This means that $p$ is contained within an open ball $B_\varepsilon(p) \subset N \subset E$.

So if $p$ is an interior point of a set $E$, there is some positive distance from $p$ to the complement of $E$. In that sense, it is "inside the set".

Your example with $X = \{ 1,2,3\}$ does not really work, even if you see it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology (which was my original interpretation). In that topology, every singleton set $\{x\}$ of $X$ is open, since $\{ x \} = X \cap B_{1/2}(x)$. Hence, every subset of $X$ is open, so every point of every subset is an interior point.

Comment: But if one considers that $X$ has no limit points, hence the set of limit points is the empty set (which is contained in $X$), wouldn't be closed under that point of view? I'm just asking .